# Why does historical price data not go back all the way on Google Finance?

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance

Compare these links:

http://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:SBAC

http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBAC?ltr=1

According to Yahoo (the second) this company has been publicly trading for over ten years. (Indeed the IPO was in 1999.) However, Google Finance only goes back to Jan. 17.

Many of us use Google over Yahoo so I'm wondering why this would be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Finance and Yahoo Finance have been transitioning their API (data interface) over the last 3 months. They are currently unreliable. If you're just interested in historical price data, I would recommend either Quandl or Tiingo (I am not affiliated with either, but I use them as data sources). Both have the same historical data (open, close, high, low, dividends, etc.) on a daily closing for thousands of Ticker symbols. Each service requires you to register and get a unique token. For basic historical data, there is no charge. I've been using both for many months and the data quality has been excellent and API (at least for python) is very easy!

If you have an inclination for python software development, you can read about the drama with Google and Yahoo finance at the pandas-datareader group at https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.

Comment: I have started using Quandl lately, actually. This just piqued my interest. Good to know that about the API.